# best practise for sql in clause with upper keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where my in clause should compare string value. For string *i* do an upper on the left and right of the in clause like below

```
select * from cases where upper(case_name) = upper(String);//value passed dynamically.
```

Now, this value is a multi-select field. So there may be more than 1 string. In that case what is the best approach to compare values.

```
select * from cases where upper(case_name) = upper('ABC');//value passed dynamically with 1 selection.

select * from cases where upper(case_name) = upper('ABC', 'BCD');//value passed dynamically with more than 1 selection.this query wont work but just showing the requirement.
```

Please let me know which would be the best approach. I have to do this in java with hibernate native query. So keeping that in mind please suggest. thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  I think you need more explanation.

Comment: `where upper(case_name) IN (upper('ABC'), upper('BCD'), ...)`

Comment: Or use a case insensitive collation.

Comment: @ jarlh I have updated my original query with in clause as you specified. i am getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 48 Column: 26

Comment: Seems like you have missed the final `)`.

Comment: If you only have two IN list items: `where upper(case_name) IN (upper('ABC'), upper('BCD'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have any number of strings to search, you can use `in` and pass a list as parameter value. I don't think you can fix the upper() around every value in the list, so you nee to change the search strings before in java to uppercase (`String.toUpperCase()`) and pass it as a list of upper cased values to your statement

```
select * from cases where upper(case_name) in (:namelist)
```

**Remark 1**: check in java if namelist is not empty, otherwise you get an SQL error because `in ()`is not valid SQL.

**Remark 2**: this will not use an index defined on `case_name`. You should create an index on 'upper(case_name)' so the upper cased values are indexed. See [Function based indexes](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12.2 you can use a case-insensitive collation:

```
select * from dual
where  dummy collate binary_ci in ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

`binary_ci` ignores case.

`binary_ai` also ignores accents.

See the [Database Globalization Support Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#id=NLSPG-GUID-D918D6AE-220B-41F0-98D8-62502B9B1DBB) for details of collation options.

In 12.2, this syntax doesn't work when cursor_sharing is set to FORCE, and you have to include a `/*+ cursor_sharing_exact */` hint. It seems not to need it in 19c, though it may have been fixed earlier.

You can in theory set this as the default for a column, but only if you also set [max_string_size](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html) to EXTENDED:

```
create or replace view demo as
select dummy collate binary_ci as dummy_ci
from   dual; 

ORA-43929: Collation cannot be specified if parameter MAX_STRING_SIZE=STANDARD is set
```

Since changing max_string_size is a system-wide setting that cannot be undone, with potential side effects, I doubt many sites are able to set default collation for columns.